# The page you requested was not found - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a basic application using the CI framework.

I have the following error:

> 404 Page Not Found
>
> The page you requested was not found.

Posted below are my code files.

My Controller code:

```
class Contact extends CI_Controller{
 
  function _Contact(){
    parent::CI_Controller();
  }
     
  /*function main(){
    $this->load->model('contact_model');
    $data = $this->books_model->general();
         
    $this->load->view('books_main',$data);
  }*/
     
  function input(){
 
    $this->load->helper('form');  
    $this->load->helper('html');      
    $this->load->model('contact_model');
     
    if($this->input->post('mysubmit')==true){
        $this->contact_model->entry_insert();
    }   
     
    $data = $this->contact_model->general();
                 
    $this->load->view('contact_input',$data);   
  }
   
}
```

Then in Model I have the following code:

```
class contact_model extends CI_Model{
     
  function _contact_model(){
    parent::Model();
    $this->load->helper('url');               
  }
   
  function entry_insert(){
    $this->load->database();
    $data = array(
              'name'=>$this->input->post('title'),
          'address'=>$this->input->post('author'),
             
              'year'=>$this->input->post('year'),
             
            );
    $this->db->insert('contact',$data);
  }
     
  function general(){
   
    $data['base']       = $this->config->item('base_url');
  
    $data['name']      = 'Name';
    $data['address']     = 'Address';
               
    $data['year']       = 'Year';
    $data['years']      = array('2007'=>'2007',
                                '2008'=>'2008',
                                '2009'=>'2009'); 
    
    $data['forminput']  = 'Student Registration';
     
    $data['fname']     = array('name'=>'name',
                                'size'=>30
                          );
    $data['faddress']    = array('name'=>'address',
                                'size'=>30
                          );
    
    return $data;   
  }
}
```

Finally, my View:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<?php $this->load->view('contact_header'); ?>
</div>

<?php echo heading($forminput,3) ?>
<?php echo form_open('books/input'); ?>
<?php echo $name       .' : '.
        form_input($fname).br(); ?>
<?php echo $address      .' : '.
        form_input($faddress).br(); ?>

<?php echo $year        .' : '.
        form_dropdown('year',$years).br(); ?>

<?php echo form_submit('mysubmit','Submit!');  ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
 
<div id="footer">
<?php $this->load->view('contact_footer'); ?>
</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Can any one please help me?

Comment: What's the URL you're trying to access?

Comment: Also what does your `.htaccess` look like?

Comment: usually we use index() or _remap() method in CI, as yours is missing and we don't have the url you're calling we need more info

Answer (score 1):

Remove this in your Contact Controller:

```
function _Contact(){
  parent::CI_Controller();
}
```

Replace with this:

```
function __construct(){
  parent::__construct();
}
```

And in your Contact Model remove this:

```
function _contact_model(){
  parent::Model();
  $this->load->helper('url');               
}
```

Replace it with this:

```
function __construct(){
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->helper('url');  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Hey,
>
> I often had similar Problems. Usually I check the following:
>
> 1. Check the Config file if the correct siteroot is set. I often had live server stuff in there.
> 2. Check in the .htaccess if the RewriteBase is set to the correct directory.
> 3. to make sure its reading the correct value an echo base_url(); (if this works its usually the .htaccess rewrite base).
>
> Hope it helps.
>
> r n8m 
>   [enter link description here][1]
>
> [1]: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/105880/

hmc

Answer (score 0):

If you have developed your application on Windows, you might have not set first character of Controllers and Models name as a capital character.

like /controllers/home.php to /controllers/Home.php

On Linux file names are case sensitive.

Note:- This is a solution to a possible problem. There may be issues of mis-configuration, server and path variables.

Possible Duplicate: [CodeIgniter "The page you requested was not found." error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633582/codeigniter-the-page-you-requested-was-not-found-error/44302412#44302412)