# CodeIgniter "The page you requested was not found." error?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having a problem with CodeIgniter. I've checked every possible solution on the internet and seems like nothing helps in my case. I'm not a big pro and it's my first time using CodeIgniter so don't be harsh with me.

routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "page";
$route['404_override'] = '';

$route['(:num)'] = "page/index/$1";
```

page.php:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Page extends CI_Controller {

    public function index($id=null) {

        $this->load->model('Image','',TRUE);
        $this->load->model('Banner','',TRUE);
        $image = $this->Image->getImageById($id);
        if (empty($image)) {
            show_404();
        }
        //db table `banner` always have three rows
        $banners=$this->Banner->getBanners();
        $data=array();
        $data['image']=$image;
        $data['banner']=$banners;
        $this->load->view('page_index', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: how did you write your `URL` to reach that ??

Comment: based on your routes, it appears the root page of the CI application will 404 base on your conditional.

Comment: change page.php to `Page.php`, On Linux platforms file names are case sensitive.

Answer (score 4):

I have read your problem. You have done mistake while saving the controller.

It should be saved in capital i.e. `Page.php` but you have saved as `page.php`

I think this will work out !

Comment: It was working OK on Windows but LINUX file naming is case sensitive. :)

Answer (score 2):

Did you construct the parent?
    Public function _*construct()
    {
        Parent::*_construct();
    }

Answer (score 2):

If you have developed your application on Windows, you might have not set first character of Controllers and Models name as a `capital character`.

like `/controllers/home.php` to `/controllers/Home.php`

On Linux file names are case sensitive.

Note:- This is a solution to a possible problem.
There may be issues of mis configuration, server and path variables.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't sound like a Codeigniter error. It could be your webserver configuration. Do you have a webserver and php server setup and configured on your machine? Have you configured an .htaccess file to replace "index.php"?

Answer (score 0):

I am also quite new to codeigniter. This is what I would do at the beginning:

1. autoload database and configure the database.php file
2. autoload helper file 'url', 'file'
3. configure your base url "://yourhost/yourworkingfolder" (if you are
   working on local host)
4. You need to route your page. Go to route.php, and give the  name of
   your default controller page name and if it seems working than you r
   good to further with additional task.

Please, correct me if I am wrong. I am a newbie to codeigniter.
Thankx

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone, The problem was that i stated in page.php that if there is no images in the database it'll show 404 page:

```
if (empty($image)) {
    show_404();
}
```

I've added two images to the DB and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

the controller will uppercase first letter if you are using Unix server